# margin-top: 0px doesn't remove vertical white space?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a html chess board. The problem is between each row there are unwanted space

I'm trying to remove vertical space between the div elements with `margin-top: 0px`. But it doesn't work? My browser is Firefox

Here is the javascript i use to generate the chess board

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "row";
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    let tile = document.createElement("div");
    tile.className = "tile";
    tile.id = `${i}_${j}`
    if (i % 2 == j % 2) {
      tile.style.background = "white"
    } else {
      tile.style.background = "gray"
    }
    row.appendChild(tile);
  }
  document.getElementById("game").appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.tile {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.row {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="game"></div>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: have you tried margin:0; and padding:0; ? even if so, do that again with !important to see if it works

Comment: and its best to check your rows in browser inspector to see if for any reason they have any margin or padding

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i just found a working solution: setting margin-top to a negative value, in my case -4px

Comment: don't use font-size:0 or line-height:0 or negative margin .. it's a vertical align issue. Use `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to `.row`.

EDIT: tried it in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "row";
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    let tile = document.createElement("div");
    tile.className = "tile";
    tile.id = `${i}_${j}`
    if (i % 2 == j % 2) {
      tile.style.background = "white"
    } else {
      tile.style.background = "gray"
    }
    row.appendChild(tile);
  }
  document.getElementById("game").appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.tile {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="game"></div>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `line-height` property of `row` to `0` will solve the issue. This will it will take the height of the elements inside it i.e. `tile`

Comment: yep, that's probaly a much better solution than mine

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution: setting margin-top to a negative value, in my case -4px